# Get xml node attribute depending on other attribute of the same node

Tags: c#, xml

For example in the xml below if I have the `id` attribute is it possible to get its corresponding `reportid` attribute in C#

The xml code:

```
<node text=" Acid Level versus Flowmeters" nodetype="1" reportid="118" id="626" />
        <node text="Level versus Flowmeters" nodetype="1" reportid="119" id="627" />
            <node text=" Bulk Levels" nodetype="1" reportid="120" id="629" />
            <node text="Caustic and HCL" nodetype="1" reportid="121" id="630" />
```

the c# code:

```
string XMLFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLReportTreePath"];
XElement sitemap = XElement.Load(XMLFile);
            XAttribute xatt = sitemap.Attribute(reportid); // where id = 630
```

Thanks

Comment: May be easier with xml serialization of you have to do it many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your xml document has a root node:

```
var reportid = sitemap.Descendants("node")
                      .Where(el => el.Attribute("id").Value == "630")
                      .Select(el => el.Attribute("reportid").Value)
                      .FirstOrDefault();

// or, lookup of all reportid by id
var lookup = sitemap.Descendants("node")
                    .ToDictionary(el => el.Attribute("id").Value, el => el.Attribute("reportid").Value);
```

Comment: used the following which is more a less the same thing, thanks for your help. _____________                                                                                                                  string XMLFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["XMLReportTreePath"];
            XElement sitemap = XElement.Load(XMLFile);
            string test = idd.ToString();
            IEnumerable<string> e = sitemap.Descendants()
                .Where(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == test)
                .Select(x => x.Attribute("reportid").Value);

            var w = e.FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
foreach (XmlNode chldNode in node.ChildNodes)
        {
                **//Read the attribute ID**
            if (chldNode.ID== 630)
            {   
              string reportid= chldNode.Attributes["reportid"].Value;  
            }
        }
```

//just one example, but from what i could understand its something like this that you want

Comment: Switching from `XElement` to `XmlNode`? It is unlikely to help OP... at very least you should make it clear in your post that you are switching one XML API for another.